# User sign/login without email or phone: anonymous user account login system

Tags: security, authentication, anonymousidentification

I'm creating a login system that doesn't require email, phone, or any other identification, making it completely anonymous, and I'm worried about the implications of a system like this.

To summarize, I'm creating a system where the user can login without providing any "real" id.

I'm currently thinking of two ways of doing this:

1. A simple "create account" with user/nickname and password, but without requesting email or phone;
2. Provide a unique string (or seed phrase) for new users. This string can be used login without any password. Anyone with that string can see and edit that account data;

• In both cases if the user loses the credentials the account can't be recovered, but I don't really care;

• The second one is more practical for the user, he only has to save a randomly generated string. The security might be lower depending on how the user saves the string, however there will nothing on the database that can be used to identify the account owner; permanent cookies can be removed;

If you are wondering, the website is a calculator that currently loses all data once the cookies expire. I'm looking for a way to give users the ability to recover previously inserted data, but I'm not interested at all in linking that data to an email or phone. **I'm not interested at all in who uses the system and how they use it.**

How bad is this idea? Are there other approaches? Making it 100% anonymous (as possible) vs security and many more implications.